# Encoding Text to remove escape characters

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding

I've previously stored a string downloaded from URL using UTF8 encoding.

```
\"TEXT LINE ONE\"\r\n\"MORE TEXT LINE\"
```

Essentially it's CSV format.  When I read the string back to manipulate it, it's obviously still got all the encoded characters.

Up to now I've worked round it, I know the escaped chars, to simply replaced them. But wanted to know what the proper way of converting string into a byte[] then into a string i could then do, `mystr = mystr.Trim('"');` on.

How do you get from the above string to a string that would work with the string functions using System.Text.Encoding?

**Update:**

The original CSV looks like

```
"TEXT LINE ONE"
"MORE TEXT LINE"
```

Ok, so not that comma separated but you get the idea.

```
// load the data from URL
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(csvUrl);
request.Timeout = 30 * 60 * 1000;
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
request.Proxy.Credentials = request.Credentials;
WebResponse response = (WebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (Stream s = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ReadFully(s)); 
}
```

In this case `str` == `\"TEXT LINE ONE\"\r\n\"MORE TEXT LINE\"`

Then I put it into a stream before serialising it.

```
using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (str)))
{
   // save
   // now it's saved with literal characters for each \"
}
```

Comment: Having `\r\n` is not CSV format.  `\"` is not the standard way to escape CSV either.

Comment: Maybe you could look into the T4 template libraries on how to properly translate escape characters to their respective characters.

Comment: these look more like escaped C# strings. Regex might be a good choice. Not sure if there is an in-built function for this.

Comment: That's right - they are escaped c# strings. They came from UTF8 encoding web request. What I don't know is why? And how to get them back?

Comment: Also, my csv didn't contain the escaped chars. I'll update with example

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understood your question, but you convert between String and byte[] by using:

```
byte[] myBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myString);
```

...and...

```
String myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myBytes);
```

You can use different encodings instead of UTF8 if you like.

Comment: I'm trying to get from \"test\" to "test" using text encoding rather than manually replacing the escape codes

Comment: I don't think that's possible. ASCII characters are usually the same across encodings. What you're seeing is (as you already know) escape characters - meaning that additional characters were inserted, NOT that the encoding was changed. You will have to stick to a replacement mechanism.

Comment: What I don't understand is why the web requests response is converted to a string that contains \" rather than just ". There must be a way of getting the file with the correct chars.

Comment: I can't answer that, but as I see you've added some new code to your question, I think you should debug it and see how the data is being transformed. Something might be happening between the execution of the web request, and when the data is being saved.